# How to reverse the "byte order" of a number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, endianness

I have a number I know to be representable as a 32-bit unsigned integer:

`num = 3735928559 # 0xDEADBEEF`

How would I (relatively easily) convert it to a number that is the representation of that original number in Ruby?

```
num = 3735928559 # 0xDEADBEEF
num.byte_swap # .byte_swap as stand-in for the process I'm looking for
num = num.byte_swap # now equal to 0xEFBEADDE, or 4,022,250,974
```

This is for the purposes of later bitshifting and bitmasking.

Comment: Try this `num = 3735928559 # 0xDEADBEEF
byte_swapped_num = [num].pack('L>').unpack('L<').first
puts byte_swapped_num`

Comment: @Rajagopalan Seems worth of an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, do you have any advice on using `pack` and `unpack` without getting a splitting headache?

Comment: To help explain @Rajagopalan's comment, the documentation for [`Array#pack`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/pack)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options.

You could convert it to a hex string via [`to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-to_s), extract the bytes using [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-scan), [`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Array.html#method-i-reverse) them, [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Array.html#method-i-join) them together and convert the result back to an integer via [`to_i`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-to_i):

```
num = num.to_s(16)   #=> "deadbeef"
         .scan(/../) #=> ["de", "ad", "be", "ef"]
         .reverse    #=> ["ef", "be", "ad", "de"]
         .join       #=> "efbeadde"
         .to_i(16)   #=> 4022250974
```

Or use a regular expression and [`sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/String.html#method-i-sub) for the reversal:

```
num = num.to_s(16)                            #=> "deadbeef"
         .sub(/(..)(..)(..)(..)/, '\4\3\2\1') #=> "efbeadde"
         .to_i(16)                            #=> 4022250974
```

Or you could use masking ([`&`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-26)) and bit shifting ([`<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C) / [`>>`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-3E-3E)) to move each byte to its new position: (combined via [`|`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Integer.html#method-i-7C))

```
num = (num & 0x000000FF) << 24 |
      (num & 0x0000FF00) << 8  |
      (num & 0x00FF0000) >> 8  |
      (num & 0xFF000000) >> 24
```

Or, as suggested by [Rajagopalan in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113203/how-to-reverse-the-byte-order-of-a-number-in-ruby#comment134232191_76113203), you could utilize Ruby's [packing and unpacking](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/packed_data_rdoc.html) methods:

```
num = [num].pack('L<').unpack1('L>')
```

`L` specifies a 32-bit unsigned integer and `<` / `>` specify little-endian and big-endian. `pack('L<')` converts the numeric value to the binary 4-byte string `"\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF"` and `unpack1('L>')` converts the string data back to a number with reversed byte order.

Comment: Good, good, better, best.

Comment: The final method using Rajagopalan's suggestion of Ruby's packing and unpacking is what ended up working.